# How do I freeze a select row header?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

How do I freeze a select row?  In my case I want row 5 to be the header that I see when scrolling down except there is only options for row 1.  How do I get around this?

Top row and first columns are not what I desire.

[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTbRz.png)

Comment: click on A6 and freeze pains based on selection.

Comment: @ScottCraner so if I click on A6 and I want row A5.  That will give me A1:A5 rows.

Comment: You can't freeze just row 5.  It is all the rows above that or nothing.  Excel does not allow the freezing of a single row unless it is row 1.

Comment: @ScottCraner I have so much data in some of my other excels and not comfortable deleting rows above as it might stop functionality.  Can I not freeze from an invisible worksheet to that excel?

Comment: You can hide rows 1 -4, then only row 5 will show.  Or scroll till only row 5 down is showing then freeze the panes.

Comment: @ScottCraner I have images above, so this isn't really practical.  Scrolling down tends to grab more than one row also.  Darn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the row below the one you want to freeze. Then in the Freeze Panes selection instead of choosing Top Row or First Column choose Freeze Panes. So in your example select the entire row 6 and then select Freeze Panes.

Comment: This can be extended to freeze both rows and columns by selecting a cell. All cells above and to the left of the selected cell will be frozen.

Comment: This gives me A1:A5 rows.  Why is that?

Comment: It will freeze all rows above the one selected. Only freezing one row in the middle of the spreadsheet is not possible.